# linux time format command

Tags: linux

Here am stacked with a  small problem.
I need to know the exact command to get the time in following format:-86400000.
But problem is from the system am getting the format like:-24:00:00.

please give me the exact command

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your desired output correctly (seconds since the epoch), you can use:

```
date +%s
```

See `man date` for the explanation of the different formats available if this isn't right.

---

(Technically, the answer to your question is to run `date +-86400000` which will format the time exactly as you asked for.  You really should improve the question...)

Answer (score 0):

As addition to Andrzejs answer:

for a shorter overview:

```
date --help
```

for a more verbose one:

```
info coreutils date invocation
```